# Streamlit: How to when pressing dataframe cell, show image?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I'm using Streamlit. And currently I have a dataframe in HTML form. In my dataframe `players`, I have a column called `Player`. And my goal is to when pressing each `players['Player']`, the dataframe closes, and an image shows corresponding to that player.
The images are stored in my app directory, and I have a column in my dataframe, called `Path`, with the path to each image. So how do I approach this problem?

```py
columns_to_display = ['Rating', 'Player', 'Position', 'Age', 'Value', 'Wages', 'Contract']
html = players[columns_to_display].to_html(index=False)
html = html.replace('<th>', '<th style="text-align: left;">')
st.write(html, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: Read the streamlit document about column config.

Comment: @ferdy Thanks for your response! I've already checked the documentatio fo st.column_config. But there realy isn't an option to make the dataframe cell to work like a button.

Maybe I can do it using "Link Column", and opening a new page with the image. 

Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Yes you can do that with link, I thought about using the query param on the link and open it, get the param and render the image.
The link can be https://yourappname.streamlit.app/photo/?image_path=your_image_path
the photo is your app's page, like pages/photo.py where you get the param and render it with  st.image(your_image_path). Read about query_params to get the your_image_path